# Getting an array key using the max() function

Tags: php

I'm using the max() function to find the largest value in an array.  I need a way to return the key of that value.  I've tried playing with the array_keys() function, but all I can get that to do is return the largest key of the array.  There has to be a way to do this but the php manuals don't mention anything.

Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
$arrCompare = array('CompareOne' => $intOne,
                    'CompareTwo' => $intTwo,
                    'CompareThree' => $intThree,
                    'CompareFour' => $intfour);

$returnThis = max($arrCompare);
```

I can successfully get the highest value of the array, I just can't get the associated key.  Any ideas?

---

Edit:  Just to clarify, using this will not work:

```
$max_key = max( array_keys( $array ) );
```

This compares the keys and does nothing with the values in the array.

Comment: It seems odd that `array_keys()` doesn't help you.

Comment: @Dor: Using `array_keys` compares the key values.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function would help you.

```
$returnThis = array_search(max($arrCompare),$arrCompare);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need all keys for max value from the source array, you can do:

```
$keys = array_keys($array, max($array));
```

Comment: Prefer this one, though it's perhaps less obvious than `array_search()`. I didn't even know that `array_keys` could take a `$search_value` as its second argument!

Comment: This returned the SECOND highest key. I went with this answer and that worked in my case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126066/search-for-highest-key-index-in-an-array

Answer (score 4):

Not a one-liner, but it will perform the required task.

```
function max_key($array)
{
    $max = max($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if ($val == $max) return $key;
    }
}
```

From http://cherryblossomweb.de/2010/09/26/getting-the-key-of-minimum-or-maximum-value-in-an-array-php/

Comment: Don't recalculate `max($array)` in each loop iteration - I very much doubt the PHP runtime is smart enough to hoist that out of the loop

Comment: @Adam: Wow. Thanks a bunch. I can't believe I missed that when I was reading it!

Comment: I tested this and it works but it is a bit verbose. I'm going to go with Miro's solution, but thank anyway.