# How to find the highest value in a associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
 $characters = [
        "Character1" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2,
        "Intelligence" => 6, "Wisdom" => 6, "Charisma" => 3],
        "Character2" => ["Strength" => 5, "Dexterity" => 4,
        "Intelligence" => 1, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 6],
        "Character3" => ["Strength" => 6, "Dexterity" => 5,
        "Intelligence" => 5, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 5]
        "Character4" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2,
        "Intelligence" => 4, "Wisdom" => 3, "Charisma" => 3]
        ];
```

So my question is as follows, how can I get the highest quality of each character. Like for Character1 it would be either Intelligence or Wisdom. I would like to echo the name of the character, the best quality and the value associated with the quality.

```
 foreach($attributs as $s_key => $value)
                {   
                    if($value > $max)
                        $max =   max($attributs);
                        $maxkey = $s_key;
                }
                echo "<li>$max , $maxkey</li>";
               
                echo "</ul>";
```

I also have this code, but it only gives me the highest number for each character without giving me the name of the quality associated with the number.

```
 foreach($characters as $names => $quality){
        echo "$names"; 
        echo max($quality);
        }
```

I know none of them work at all, but that's as close as I could get to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest value of an array using `max` function, meanwhile the key using `array_search()`. This will fail if you have 2 skills with the same value, assuming that "Intellegence" is 6 and "Wisdom" is 6 only "Intellegence" will be shown. Do you have to shown both of them or only one ?

```
$characters = [
    "Character1" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2, "Intelligence" => 6, "Wisdom" => 6, "Charisma" => 3],
    "Character2" => ["Strength" => 5, "Dexterity" => 4, "Intelligence" => 1, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 6],
    "Character3" => ["Strength" => 6, "Dexterity" => 5, "Intelligence" => 5, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 5],
    "Character4" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2, "Intelligence" => 4, "Wisdom" => 3, "Charisma" => 3]
];

foreach ($characters as $key => $character){
    $value = max($character);
    $skill = array_search($value, $character);
    $characters[$key]['highest_skill'] =  ['skill' => $skill, 'value' => $value];
} 

print_r($characters["Character1"]);
// this will be shown
Array ( [Strength] => 1 [Dexterity] => 2 [Intelligence] => 6 [Wisdom] => 6 [Charisma] => 3 [highest_skill] => Array ( [skill] => Intelligence [value] => 6 ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a combination of `max` and `array_search` to [get the highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068724/getting-an-array-key-using-the-max-function) for each character

Optionally, use a temp object were we will 'save' the highest key and value. This extra loop is shown in the demo, but can be removed if you move the `echo` after the `array_search`

---

```php
<?php

    $characters = [
        "Character1" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2, "Intelligence" => 6, "Wisdom" => 6, "Charisma" => 3],
        "Character2" => ["Strength" => 5, "Dexterity" => 4, "Intelligence" => 1, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 6],
        "Character3" => ["Strength" => 6, "Dexterity" => 5, "Intelligence" => 5, "Wisdom" => 1, "Charisma" => 5],
        "Character4" => ["Strength" => 1, "Dexterity" => 2, "Intelligence" => 4, "Wisdom" => 3, "Charisma" => 3]
    ];

    $res = new \stdClass();

    foreach ($characters as $name => $char) {
        $highest = array_search(max($char), $char);
        $res->{$name} = [ $highest, $char[$highest] ];
    }

    foreach ($res as $name => $val) {
        echo "Highest for {$name} is {$val[0]}! Value: {$val[1]}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Output:

```
Highest for Character1 is Intelligence! Value: 6
Highest for Character2 is Charisma! Value: 6
Highest for Character3 is Strength! Value: 6
Highest for Character4 is Intelligence! Value: 4
```

---

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZJdS8MwFIbv9yuOZRcrTLFbuwvn5sUUJggOBnpRyzh0x6XQdiWJujH622sS27mPgBfmKudNzvu8@ShYUVW3dwUrWi1Qox0z5BhL4gJGEBpND2fS6J4DozGEzlxyyleSmdLrgnNPG7WcyK1Rekp5zCWlabKiPCYjDpT4mojlOtuX2jcRGRqhH3UtxJ6NGJwRfRvROyZ6p8SBldi3EQdnxMBGDP4gBlai/49b9Y@J/fNbNcBoWD8xJ/22OX3Bm5DLSYpCdNx68X3NCWMGncOPgALaOWakzYzuwm5/hjZLVoyEVJbIOW4XgpDHrJPh5sfE7dZNw98eFeFyvDOmpf5ne5d6b9jUkY6tW8rTfPoUR8E@MT3MRTFbgzOtw6k@aHiJUFO1O7yOygt4wfSDbmrFi0oHrmA2nS0enp8aclV9Aw)

---

**Note**: If there are multiple keys with the same (highest) value, the first will be used!

Answer (score -1):

Though `Ostone0` is right in his approach, but I assume it does not need to be this complicated. Just try the following to get what you want. It is easier and much more straightforward.

```
foreach ($characters as $character => $names) {
  $quality = array_search(max($names), $names);
  $max = max($names);
  echo 'The highest value for '. $character . ' is ' . $max . ' for the quality ' . $quality.   PHP_EOL ;
}
```

**This will output the following**:

```
The highest value for Character1 is 6 for the quality Intelligence
The highest value for Character2 is 6 for the quality Charisma
The highest value for Character3 is 6 for the quality Strength
The highest value for Character4 is 4 for the quality Intelligence
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJPa4NAEMXvfopBBC2IYNRcbNpDW2ih0EALPQQJy3bqCv7r7qYklH52u67RmhhS6mHhzbw3v2HXmtVNc3lds9qwKCOcUIlcwAJWBqjPvOlrvgmLK1iZz5JjmUqmpe@CeYtb1c7kTldmrs7p7EMpMc@zFEuKujlX9tdMvFXFINv5mSiILgSJe0SdnaJGE2p4juofUv1j6nxCDU5R5xNqdI4a/UGNklF6IIf/uuUpNTykBtMbHqBJbLxXHAll4Iyfngj4lW3GKkmB4gK@dNT62JBc7aF@EcI52a0FEk6ZU5Cts3e6fSTuEqql3CNDV0fKKrBfGALLUoZCwifJNwhqK7C98RIe2JAJdXjdsFa3Lqmy/Tq6uReemr68X67vnh4hNr6b5gc)