# Select the highest key based on its value in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql database website that isn't working and I'm hoping for a little help.

This is the effect I would like to achieve: I have 3 categories (commenter, visitor, and owner) each with a different integer values that is pulled from a database ($total1, $total2, $total3 respectively). I want to compare the 3 values of $total and find out which one is the highest. If $total2 is the highest, I want the value of $Popular to be set at "visitor"; if $total3 is the highest, I want $Popular to be "owner).

I tried to do this:

```
$Popular_array = array ('commenter' => $total1, 'visitor' => $total2, 'owner' => $total3);
$Popular = max (array_keys ($Popular_array));
```

but this was the result when I output the variables using print_r:

```
Array ( [commenter] => 50 [visitor] => 13 [owner] => 38 ) 
owner
```

I have already read [Search for highest key/index in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126066/search-for-highest-key-index-in-an-array) but it is not quite what I'm looking for because the solution above does not work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing your keys, not values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you're comparing your keys, not values.
So you need to fetch the key of the highest-valued array member. You can do it like this:

```
$Popular = array_search( max($Popular_array), $Popular_array );
```

See it in action here: http://ideone.com/Np6xp6

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looking for the maximum **key** instead of **value**, which will not return the desired result.  You would need to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) then [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search):

```
$Popular_array = array ('commenter' => $total1, 'visitor' => $total2, 'owner' => $total3);
$Popular = array_search (max (array_values ($Popular_array)), $Popular_array);
```