# How to know the last index of an disorder array

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [2] => -100 [0] => -7.1 )
```

It is not ordered because if I sort this array, it will become this array into this Array ( [0] => -7.1 [1] => -100) and I am not looking for that, I just want to know the index value of an array like that....

In this case if I use the php function to know the last index it shows me 0 BUT althought it's in the last position the last index really is 2, how can I get 2 and not 0?

I am not using PHP 7, I am using PHP 5

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for highest key/index in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126066/search-for-highest-key-index-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no regularity in your proposed array structure, use `max(array_keys($arr))`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the function `array_key_last()`. It's return the last key of an array. Here is an example (PHP 7+):

```php
// array_key_last()  ( array $array ) : mixed

$arr = [
    '2' => 3,
    '5' => 2,
    '0' => 10
];

print_r(array_key_last($arr));
```

UPDATE

In PHP 7 there is no `array_key_last()` function, so in PHP 5 we can use `end()` with `key()`. 
Function `end()` set the pointer of array to the last element and return it. Function `key()` return the key of the current element of array. Example:

```php
$arr = [
    '2' => 3,
    '5' => 2,
    '0' => 10
];

end($arr);
print_r(key($arr));
```

Comment: I am not using PHP 7 so it does not work to me

Comment: @JesúsCova update for PHP 5

Comment: Upvoted your answer.

Comment: It would not work, because end() will display the index 0 as last one, and it's not correct I already tried it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using PHP7, you can use `count` minus 1

```php
$a = array(5, 3, 4);
print_r($a[count($a) - 1]);
```

Comment: This is incorrect for OP's example. His max index is 2, even though the array only contains two elements. Meaning there's risk of an undefined index error.

Comment: Those details weren't there when he first posted it.

Comment: @El_Vanja I know that it is one undefined index, for that reason I said an array like that

Comment: Yes, I understood that, I was just explaining why this solution wouldn't work.